# Symfony2 : JMSSecurityExtraBundle : #id == user.getId() in @PreAuthorize not working

Tags: symfony, annotations

I try to access a function in a controller securing it by @PreAuthorize annotation (Symfony2 2.1.8) :

When I write :

```
/*    
* @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or #id == '5'")
*/

public function editAction($id){ 
(...)
```

I can get throught
but when I use :

```
/*    
* @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or #id == user.getId()")
*/

public function editAction($id){ 
(...)
```

I get a "Token does not have the required roles. " error and Yes I am logged and authenticated with the right id...

Any idea someone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out...

Basically the PreAuthorize annotation is doing this

```
user.getId() === '5'
```

Where getId is returning an integer and doing a comparison against a string.  I managed to get it working by adding this method to my User entity:

```
public function getStringId()
{
    return (string) $this->id;
}
```

Then changing the annotation to this

```
@PreAuthorize("user.getStringId() == '2' and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

Hope that helps!